# Put foreach data into a varible and add the varible to a database

Tags: php, database, foreach

I've been searching and I've tried multiple ways with no luck, What's happening in my code looks for a link. It will then determine what type of link it is and adjust it to suit my needs. Once adjusted I need it to go into an Array with the end goal of adding that Array to my database. print_r($items) will be where ill be adding the array to the Database if you know how do do this also I will not say no to the help :D I am guessing it the same as adding a variable to the database.

Here is my code so far :)

```
                //Lets look for links
            $urlcomp = array(); 
            $items = array();
            foreach($html->find('a') as $element){

                if( strpos( $element->href, "http" ) !== false) {  

                    $urlcomp[] = $element->href; 

                    // Look for gov websites
                    if ((strpos($urlcomp, 'gov') !== false) || (strpos($urlcomp, 'police') !== false) || (strpos($urlcomp, 'nhs') !== false) || (strpos($urlcomp, 'org') !== false) || (strpos($urlcomp, 'council') !== false)){
                    } else { 


                        if (in_array($urlcomp, $websiteurlall)) {
                        }else{ 

                            echo "First Batch  -  " . $urlcomp; 
                            $items[] = array($urlcomp); 
                            echo "</br>";  

                        }

                    }                       

                }else{ 

                    $urlcomp = $websiteurlcomp.$element->href;   

                    // Look for gov websites
                    if ((strpos($urlcomp, 'gov') !== false) || (strpos($urlcomp, 'police') !== false) || (strpos($urlcomp, 'nhs') !== false) || (strpos($urlcomp, 'org') !== false) || (strpos($urlcomp, 'council') !== false)){   
                    } else { 


                        if (in_array($urlcomp, $websiteurlall)) {
                        }else{

                            echo "Second Batch  -  " . $urlcomp;
                            $items[] = array($urlcomp);
                            echo "</br>";  

                        } 
                    } 
                }  
            } 


            print_r($items);
```

Comment: is this code already working fine ? at this point above `print_r($items)` ?

Comment: Yep, all works perfectly, Displays the 12 URLs from ( echo "Second Batch  -  " . $urlcomp; ) but print_r($items) is showing nothing

Comment: can you also post the array which you are running in your for loop, you can use dummy values for the array and I'll run your code and see what I can do to help.

Comment: it would be $html = file_get_html("http://www.megafone.co.uk/contact/"); will fill $urlcomp with http://www.megafone.co.uk/contact/mailto:hello@megafone.co.uk

Comment: it doesn't work like this, write the `var_dump($html)` after you call `file_get_html` function

Comment: but I need to tell it to find the links and store them in a variable first, dumping the $html will just show the whole website

Comment: oh okay, so you are getting the result from curl ?

Comment: No i am getting it from Simple_HTML_DOM :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$urlcomp[] = $element->href;  should have been $urlcomp = $element->href; that was the only issue :S

Comment: glad you found it, haha,